# Grid systems on retina display

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, retina-display

I hope this isn't an awful question, but how do grid systems like 960 or bootstrap play with retina displays?

1. If I design for 1170px on a non-retina display but it's viewed on a retina display, will my site and images look blurry on retina?
2. Do I just have to worry about images or is there anything else I have to worry about when designing?

Am I missing something here? :O

Comment: The point of "retina" displays is that they provide a virtual resolution that maps to a much higher physical resolution. You don't have to worry about it, it will look the same except your fonts will be crisper. They wouldn't be very useful if, when they had come out, every single website rendered too small to read.

Comment: When I create a site I use css preprocessors, which then easily change one value (`width layout`, targeting by `media query`) and the rest is already automatically calculated using relative values (`em` or `%`) and I don't need any grid system like bootstrap, foundation or 960.